# How to set Matching Modes in SPhinxql query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sphinx, sphinxql

This is my query

```
$query =SphinxQL::query()->select('*')
    ->from('property_table')->match('property_title','Plo',)->execute();

//property_title is  column name
```

Not retrieving the records with the data `'Plo'`

I need a records which is having the `%Plo%`. Help me pls

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like anything to do with Match Modes. (Match modes are a legacy from the old API, best avoided in SphinxQL. )

Sphinx by default matches WHOLE words only. to be able to match part words, need to enable it on the index, with `min_infix_len`/`min_prefix_len` ideally with `enable_star`=1 - then you would be able to use wildcards in your keywords, eg

```
->match('property_title','*Plo*')
```

If your index is big, or performance is critical then may want to experiment with `dict` option.